# Auth failure implementing X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication using Objective-C and C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, facebook, authentication, xmpp

I'm implementing the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM XMPP authentication in Objective C (but using mostly C++ code) and I am getting always a failure:
`<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>`

I have the the app registered and the Id and Secret are as follows:

FacebookId  @"136973476410894"
FacebookSecret   @"f6e269fe158b4a04d00ce8b311453ccd"

I retrieve the session Token with FBConnect asking for the privileges:
@"publish_stream" ,@"xmpp_login" , @"offline_access"

The Session token is called token in the code (see below)

And then the program asks for the authentication mechanism:
`<auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM"/>`

Receiving the challenge: `<challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dmVyc2lvbj0xJm1ldGhvZD1hdXRoLnhtcHBfbG9naW4mbm9uY2U9OTAzMTM5MjY2ODk3N0Q0ODMyNDQ2MDY1REMzMTE5RTc=</challenge>`

**Then the Facebook Auth body extracted from the challenge:** version=1&method=auth.xmpp_login&nonce=9031392668977D4832446065DC3119E7.
key: version, value: 1.
key: method, value: auth.xmpp_login.
key: nonce, value: 9031392668977D4832446065DC3119E7.
token: "BAAB8k59ntg4BANNuTHAkjTZBk3pW8pZBD7jWIpZBt8cf65oAT4eDm9euloGCX9NzfF9HwKQxUdEQ15YfeFtkdZAHVpkjL0j4CF0lZCQeuNTBXrvkbtUXC"
APIkey: "136973476410894"
APISecret: "f6e269fe158b4a04d00ce8b311453ccd"

**Using the code from below a response is built:**

token = Session token from FB connect: (BAAB8k59ntg4BANNuTHAkjTZBk3pW8pZBD7jWIpZBt8cf65oAT4eDm9euloGCX9NzfF9HwKQxUdEQ15YfeFtkdZAHVpkjL0j4CF0lZCQeuNTBXrvkbtUXC)

APIkey = FacebookId (136973476410894);

APISecret = FacebookSecret (f6e269fe158b4a04d00ce8b311453ccd);

```
string call_id=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] UTF8String];
string signature1 = "api_key=" + APIkey
+ "call_id=" + call_id
+ "method=auth.xmpp_login"
+ "nonce=" + nonce
+ "session_key=" + token
+ "v=1.0"
+ APISecret;

string md = MD5(signature1);

//std::transform(md.begin(), md.end(),md.begin(), ::tolower);
string response2 = "method=auth.xmpp_login&api_key=" + APIkey + "&session_key=" +token + "&call_id=" + call_id + "&sig=" + md + "&v=1.0&" + "nonce=" + nonce;

printf("++base64EncodedResponse response2: %s.\n", response2.c_str());

string response2Base64 = Base64::Encode(response2);
```

Built response: `method=auth.xmpp_login&api_key=136973476410894&session_key=BAAB8k59ntg4BANNuTHAkjTZBk3pW8pZBD7jWIpZBt8cf65oAT4eDm9euloGCX9NzfF9HwKQxUdEQ15YfeFtkdZAHVpkjL0j4CF0lZCQeuNTBXrvkbtUXC&call_id=1321457495&sig=5f376192b2dd1f5f928f651a996ce757&v=1.0&nonce=9031392668977D4832446065DC3119E7`

Stanza sent(response): `<response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">bWV0aG9kPWF1dGgueG1wcF9sb2dpbiZhcGlfa2V5PTEzNjk3MzQ3NjQxMDg5NCZzZXNzaW9uX2tleT1CQUFCOGs1OW50ZzRCQU5OdVRIQWtqVFpCazNwVzhwWkJEN2pXSXBaQnQ4Y2Y2NW9BVDRlRG05ZXVsb0dDWDlOemZGOUh3S1F4VWRFUTE1WWZlRnRrZFpBSFZwa2pMMGo0Q0YwbFpDUWV1TlRCWHJ2a2J0VVhDJmNhbGxfaWQ9MTMyMTQ1NzQ5NSZzaWc9NWYzNzYxOTJiMmRkMWY1ZjkyOGY2NTFhOTk2Y2U3NTcmdj0xLjAmbm9uY2U9OTAzMTM5MjY2ODk3N0Q0ODMyNDQ2MDY1REMzMTE5RTc=</response>`

And the server returns: 
    `<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>`

I don't know where the problem is, it looks right to me, but there is no way to authenticate. Does anybody knows if there is any way to debug with the server the reason for the failure?  May it be that the App is not yet in the App Store?

If someone can help it would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one responded and someone else can get tricked by this same error due to the fact that this code appears on some examples about Facebook Authentication- I will post the response myself.

Everything is almost ok, it only requires the tag  **session_key** to be changed for **access_token** in the signature1 string and in the response2 string.